# How to make this JS work for all elements, rather than the first one?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which, when paired with right CSS, allows you to drag and scroll on an element, even on desktop.

The `querySelector` works based on the ID containing `tb-drag-scroll-`

I have multiple elements on the same page with IDs that match this... e.g.

```
<div id="tb-drag-scroll-1"></div>
<div id="tb-drag-scroll-2"></div>
```

However, the JS only works for the first div. I understand why *(kind of)* but I'm struggling to re-write the code so that it works for every element with a matching ID. Can anyone help?

```
const dragScroll = document.querySelector('[id^="tb-drag-scroll-"]')
let isDown = false
let startX
let scrollLeft

dragScroll.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  isDown = true
  dragScroll.classList.add("active")
  startX = e.pageX - dragScroll.offsetLeft
  scrollLeft = dragScroll.scrollLeft
})
dragScroll.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  isDown = false
  dragScroll.classList.remove("active")
})
dragScroll.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  isDown = false
  dragScroll.classList.remove("active")
})
dragScroll.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return
  e.preventDefault()
  const x = e.pageX - dragScroll.offsetLeft
  const walk = x - startX
  dragScroll.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk
  console.log(walk)
})
```

I tried to re-write based on this scope but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Probably want to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the results.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that now.. if you have time to show me how the iteration might look, it'd be really appreciated.

Comment: Literally the same as iterating over any other array-like: `querySelectorAll(...).forEach( (element) => { ... })`

Comment: Array-like objects don't have to have a `forEach`, just indexes and a non-negative length. So maybe not quite _literally_ the same, from your example :) Kinda harsh language anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` since you want to affect all of your divs with that id and then iterate thru them. Since `querySelectorAll` returns an array like object, you want to access each element by its index

```js
const dragScroll = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="tb-drag-scroll-"]')
let isDown = false
let startX
let scrollLeft

for (let i = 0; i < dragScroll.length; i++) {
    dragScroll[i].addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    isDown = true
    dragScroll[i].classList.add("active")
    startX = e.pageX - dragScroll[i].offsetLeft
    scrollLeft = dragScroll[i].scrollLeft
  })
  dragScroll[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    isDown = false
    dragScroll[i].classList.remove("active")
  })
  dragScroll[i].addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      isDown = false
      dragScroll[i].classList.remove("active")
  })
dragScroll[i].addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return
    e.preventDefault()
    const x = e.pageX - dragScroll[i].offsetLeft
    const walk = x - startX
    dragScroll[i].scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk
    console.log(walk)
    })   
}
```

```html
<div id="tb-drag-scroll-1">div1</div>
<div id="tb-drag-scroll-2">div2</div>
```

Comment: note that the result is array-like enough that it comes with `.forEach`, no need for loop counters.

Comment: Such a simple explanation, thank you so much! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers... combining advice in comments, looks like the best way to do this is:

```
const dragScroll = document
  .querySelectorAll('[id^="tb-drag-scroll-"]')
  .forEach((dragScroll) => {
    let isDown = false
    let startX
    let scrollLeft

    dragScroll.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      isDown = true
      dragScroll.classList.add("active")
      startX = e.pageX - dragScroll.offsetLeft
      scrollLeft = dragScroll.scrollLeft
    })
    dragScroll.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      isDown = false
      dragScroll.classList.remove("active")
    })
    dragScroll.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      isDown = false
      dragScroll.classList.remove("active")
    })
    dragScroll.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (!isDown) return
      e.preventDefault()
      const x = e.pageX - dragScroll.offsetLeft
      const walk = x - startX
      dragScroll.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk
      console.log(walk)
    })
  })
```